# How can i add intcomma in django messages template

Tags: python, django

After add **extra_tags='safe'** in views , and **{{ messages|safe }}** in templates, how can i add **|intcomma**, humanize, in message ???

[template code]

[template show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vn3ky.png)

[view code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bpmgf.png)

Comment: spelling, formatting, context, missing code samples. start with: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry, i have bad english. So i will try show example here

Answer (score 2):

I find solution doing it:

In my view, i add:

```
from django.contrib.humanize.templatetags.humanize import intcomma
```

and in message, the variable that I liked humanize,

```
intcomma(variable)
```